# JQuery Ajax Submit Function add validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code:

```
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', 
          url: 'index.php', 
          data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {   
              $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
            }}
    );
    return false;
}
```

It works well but how do I go about adding a validation for example ... to alert if username or password is empty?

I know there's a lot of these similar scripts around but want to add it to this one in particular.

Comment: Should the validation be before or after the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitForm() {
if(!$("#name").val()){
   alert("name field is empty.");
   return false;
}    


$.ajax({type:'POST', 
    url: 'index.php', 
    data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `beforeSend()`

```
  function submitForm() {
  $.ajax({type:'POST', 
      url: 'index.php', 
      data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(),
      success: function(response) {   
          $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
        }},
      beforeSend: function(){
        if(!$("#name").val()){
          alert("name field is empty.");
           return false;
          }    
      }
    );
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform validation before the ajax calling statement

for example

```
function submitForm() {

var username=$('#id').value;
if(username!='')
{
    $.ajax({type:'POST', 

            url: 'index.php', 

            data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {

              $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);

            }});
}
else
{
alert("Please Enter Username");
}

            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this

```
function submitForm() {
    if (inputIsValid()) {
        sendAjaxRequest();
    } else {
        ShowMessage();
    }
}

function sendAjaxRequest(parameters) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: $('#ContactForm').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
        }
    });
}

function inputIsValid() {
    return $("#username").val() && $("#password").val();
}

function ShowMessage() {
    alert("Please provide username and password");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for reference http://jsfiddle.net/RH8Dy/ to view the example or below given Script

```
function submit()
{
var username = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
var password = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
if(username == "")
{
alert("enter username");
}
if(username == "")
{
alert("enter username");
 }
else if(password == "")
{
    alert("Enter Password");
}
else
{
//ajax call
}
}
```